# Break an absolutely positioned element out of its relatively positioned ancestor?

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

Suppose I have a document like

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
  border:1px solid;
  padding:15px;
}

#i_am_relatively_positioned{
  background-color:#fcc;
  margin:50px;
  padding:50px;
  position:relative;
}

#inner {
  background-color:#cfc;
}

#i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body{
  background-color:#ccf;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div id="i_am_relatively_positioned">
    <div id="inner">inner</div>
    <div id="i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body">absolute to body</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to make #i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body positioned absolute with respect to the body element, rather than its immediate relative container?

I know I can just use some negative top and left but that seems kludgey - is this my only option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a bit of javascript to do this (I'm assuming you can't change the markup?).

```
document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body'));
```

Comment: I suppose to be most correct, I'd also have to remove the old element so that there aren't two elements with the same ID:

    var el = document.getElementById('i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body');
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    document.body.appendChild(el);

Comment: No, that breaks things (tested in IE8 & Chrome). Just do the appendChild and the node is moved in the DOM.  I have to do this with SharePoint and another CMS that a client uses (for similar reasons as what you're doing, typically I'm moving an element from one container to another).

Answer (score 0):

Is it important, that the Element "i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body" is in the Container "i_am_relatively_positioned"?

If not then this solution:

```
  <div id="i_am_relatively_positioned">
  <div id="inner">inner</div>
  </div>
  <div id="i_want_to_be_absolute_to_body">absolute to body</div>
```

Comment: Due to the way the document is built at render time, it's not easy to move this element elsewhere.